# Link two sets of plots together side by side horizontally or vertically

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I have two sets of plots below. Now I'm plotting them separately.  
 I want to plot each the corresponding plot from each plot together side by side horizontally or vertically. 
 Corresponding plot means plot with the same set of combination from `tup1` like the first graph of `f1` is linked with the first graph of `f2`. 
How can I do that?

```
check[x_] := If[x == -1, 1, 0];
tup1 = {{0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 
    1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 1,
     0, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, -1}};
f1[a_, b_, c_, m_, n_, p_, d_] := -((m + d (a + b - m - n) + n) /(
   c d + p - d p));
f2[x_, y_, d_] := 1/(x*(1 - d) + y *d) /. d -> 1 - 1/m;

fig1[tup_, f_] :=
  Plot[{f[##, d], 1, f2[check[{##}[[6]]], check[{##}[[3]]], d]}, {d, 
      0, 1}, PlotLabel -> {Style[
        StringForm["a= `` b= `` c= `` m= `` n= `` p= ``", ##], 
        FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 30, Blue, Bold]}, 
     ImageSize -> 1500, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], 
       Directive[Blue, Dashed, Thick], Directive[Green, Thick]}, 
     Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
     GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
     AxesLabel -> {Style["D", 16, Bold], Style["A", 16, Bold]}] & @@@ 
   tup;
fig2[tup_, f_] :=
  Plot[{1, f2[check[{##}[[6]]], check[{##}[[3]]], m]}, {m, 0, 10}, 
     PlotLabel -> {Style[
        StringForm["a= `` b= `` c= `` m= `` n= `` p= ``", ##], 
        FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 30, Blue, Bold]}, 
     ImageSize -> 1500, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
       Directive[Blue, Thick]}, Ticks -> Automatic, 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], GridLines -> Automatic,
      GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
     AxesLabel -> {Style["M", 16, Bold], Style["N", 16, Bold]}] & @@@ 
   tup;
fig1[tup1, f1] // Flatten // Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
fig2[tup1, f2] // Flatten // Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
```

Comment: can you post the definition of  `check`?

Comment: Oops, I thought I added it. I'll edit it. `check[x_] := If[x == -1, 1, 0];` 
Btw, PlotGrid works well too. It took me sometime to make it work though. 
@kglr

Comment: try `Grid@Transpose[{fig1[tup1, f1], fig2[tup1, f1]}]`?

Comment: ... or `Multicolumn[Join[fig1[tup1, f1], fig2[tup1, f1]], 2]`?

Comment: `ResourceFunction[
  "PlotGrid"][{Plot[{f1[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> {Style[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 30, Blue, Bold]}, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
     AxesLabel -> {Style["D", 16, Bold], Style["N", 16, Bold]}],
    Plot[{1, f2[check[{##}[[6]]], check[{##}[[3]]], m]}, {m, 0, 10}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
       Directive[Blue, Thick]}, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
     AxesLabel -> {Style["M", 16, Bold], Style["A", 16, Bold]}]} & @@@
   tup1, Spacings -> {30, 100}]`

Comment: This is what I've used. I'll try that.

Comment: Your suggestion works well too. Is it possible to add one frame for these two figures and use the same label for set of `["a= `` b= `` c= `` m= `` n= `` p= ``"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[rowfig12]
rowfig12[tup_, f1_, f2_] := Labeled[Row[{
   Plot[{f1[##, d], 1, f2[check[{##}[[6]]], check[{##}[[3]]], d]}, {d, 0, 1}, 
        ImageSize -> 400, 
        PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], 
          Directive[Blue, Dashed, Thick], Directive[Green, Thick]}, 
        Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
        GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
        AxesLabel -> {Style["D", 16, Bold], Style["A", 16, Bold]}],
       Plot[{1, f2[check[{##}[[6]]], check[{##}[[3]]], m]}, {m, 0, 10}, 
        ImageSize -> 400, 
        PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
          Directive[Blue, Thick]}, Ticks -> Automatic, 
        TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
        GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
        AxesLabel -> {Style["M", 16, Bold], Style["N", 16, Bold]}]}, Spacer[10]], 
     Style[StringForm["a= `` b= `` c= `` m= `` n= `` p= ``", ##], 
      FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 20, Blue, Bold], Top] & @@@ tup;

Column[rowfig12[tup1, f1, f2], Spacings -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice.